# Bundle .NET 5.0 Runtime with *WINDOWS FORMS* App

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

When running my Windows Forms application on a fresh system, it says "This app requires .NET to run" and prompts the user (me, in this case) to download the .NET runtime. However, is there a way I can bundle the runtime (or include it inside the app) so it can directly run without the user having to manually install it?

I tried searching this on the web, but all the solutions didn't work. The closest I got was here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/prerequisites-dialog-box?view=vs-2019. However, I can't find that dialog box inside my IDE.

**My question then got marked as duplicate, however, the question which I was linked to is about publishing .NET *Console* apps, while the app I'm trying to publish is a *Windows Forms (GUI)* app, and so the article doesn't help me.**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't you just use a [Single File Compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file)?

Comment: @Andy Would that include the .NET Runtimes required? Edit: I'm asking because the page is a bit unclear.

Comment: Yes, it does include everything.